# If it's leak memory if retained Fragment keep reference to it's View element?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I have an activity, in the activity I have only a container layout and an Fragment with its own layout, and has been setRetainInstance to true.

First time the activity create, I add this fragment to container, and fragment has a reference to View object of Fragment's layout (a Button for example).

When configuration change occur, will memory leak occur, I wonder if the View object still have reference to old Activity ?

Comment: Do not keep references to old resources. Sometimes you will find that they cause `NullPointerException` crashes. Instead, make required fields `static` methods (e.g. `getFeild()`) that checks first if filed is null then initialize it, after that return the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Do not keep references to old resources. Sometimes you will find that they cause NullPointerException crashes. Instead, make required fields static methods (e.g. getFeild()) that checks first if filed is null then initialize it, after that return the field value.

***Example (Bad)***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public SomeType myImportantObj;
}
...
//in another place
Object o = mainActivity.myImportantObj; // this could be null !!
```

***Good***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}

public class SomeType {
   private static SomeType instance;
   public static SomeType getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) instance = new SomeType();
       return instance;
   }
}
...
//in other place
Object o = SomeType.getInstance();
```

Comment: Bad. Avoid using statics.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Can you elaborate why it is bad (the 2nd approach)?